# Declaring and initializing a completely `const` `char *argv[]`

Tags: c, gcc-warning, gcc4

I tried assigning the `argv` value to a constant pointer, believing that it's safe to assign a non-const to a const variable.

Unfortunately `gcc` complained:

```text
> make CFLAGS=-Wall mein
cc -Wall    mein.c   -o mein
mein.c: In function ‘main’:
mein.c:5:30: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  const char *const*const a = argv + 1;
                              ^~~~
mein.c:5:26: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
  const char *const*const a = argv + 1;
```

The corresponding C source looks like this:

```c
2021-07-08 13:49                      mein.c                      Page 1


    1   #include <stdlib.h>
    2   
    3   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    4   {
    5       const char *const*const a = argv + 1;
    6       return 0;
    7   }
```

I believe my declaration says `a` is a constant pointer to an array of constant pointers pointing to constant strings.
I also believe that `char *argv[]` is equivalent to `char **argv`.

The question is: Am I wrong, or is gcc wrong?

Comment: "While true programmers do not need `const`" - something on the line "true programmers write everything in 0 and 1". I don't know who told you that, but it's crap. Please write const-correct code.

Comment: @StefanRiedel As the "true programmer" is a kind of joke (from today's perspective), everything said about *true programmers* is considered to be a joke. Or maybe think my statement was simply irony.

Comment: @4386427 As obviously I don't see the problem, maybe explain in greater detail.

Comment: Ok I see. It's hard to differentiate irony from bad mindset here on SO.

Comment: The types are incompatible, but their byte representations are the same. You could use an explicit type cast operation to do the conversion, e.g. `const char *const*const a = (const char *const *)argv + 1;`

Comment: in short, what Eric just said: the leading `const` is the problem. `char * const * const a` should work.

Comment: True programmers know the constraints for adding qualifiers in an initialization (inherited from assignment) allow adding qualifiers to the pointed-to type but not to subcomponents within that.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Sorry to delete the comment you referred to, but I had to make a correction.

Comment: `const char *const*const a = (const char **)argv + 1;` would also work and is shorter than my previous one.

Comment: See the explanation for why this isn't allowed in the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html

Comment: @4386427 The site's main page says "This collection of hypertext pages is Copyright 1995-2005 by Steve Summit.".

Comment: Simplifying the question: `char ** p = NULL; const char** cp = p;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For initialization, C 2018 6.7.9 11 says:

> … the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply…

For simple assignment, 6.5.16.1 1 says:

> One of the following shall hold: … the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;…

For this purpose, the “left operand” is the `a` with type `const char * const * const` and the “right operand” is `argv + 1` with type `char **`. The type the left operand points to is `const char * const`, and the type the right operand points to is `char *`.

The left operand is a qualified version of `const char *`, and the right operand is an unqualified version of `char *`. Then this initialization conforms to the constraints if the former type (`const char *`) is compatible with the latter (`char *`).

6.7.6.1 2 says:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

So `const char *` and `char *` are compatible if `const char` and `char` are compatible.

6.7.3 11 says:

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect the specified type.

Since `const char` is `const` qualified and `char` is not, these are not compatible types.

Therefore, this initialization does not conform to the constraints of the C standard.

> The question is: Am I wrong, or is gcc wrong?

GCC is right, you are wrong.

Comment: This is hard to digest: So essentially the "middle `const`" causes the problem, but why can't I assign an array of pointers to an array of constant pointers? OTOH `char *const *c = argv + 1;` causes no error (just as assigning `char *` to `const char *`).